# The difference between 你不知道吗？/你知道吗？/不知道吗？/知道吗？

Tags: yes-no-questions

> > 1.　明天会下雪，你不知道吗？
> >
> > 2.　明天会下雪，你知道吗？
> >
> > 3.　明天会下雪，不知道吗？
> >
> > 4.　明天会下雪，知道吗？

What are the possible pragmatic/semantic differences between these four questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 & 3 are the same with 3 omitting subject. Like in English, negative interrogative sentences are usually used for rhetorical questions.

> A: Let's play football tomorrow. I just booked the field.
>
> B: The forecast says it's going to snow. **Haven't you checked?** (How could you organize a game without knowing the weather?)

2 & 4 could be either a simple question.

> A: Do you feel like going picnic tomorrow.
>
> B: It's going to snow. **Have you heard?**

Or in certain situation, it can be a challenge about whether the listener truly understand the consequences of snow weather.

> A: Should I water the lawn?
>
> B: It's going to snow tomorrow. **Do you understand what that means?** (As if A already knew the fact that it's going to snow.)

Answer (score 0):

They mean similar. It depends how you use them and the tones you use.

Basically, 1 & 3 sound like you should know it. Well, 2 & 4 usually are generic questions for checking whether you know it.